# insert giving error not all arguments converted python

Tags: python, postgresql

Extracting data from csv into a dataframe. Then create a table. After table creation insert the records from dataframe into the `loc_dem` table. With the code and Sample of data:

abbr    state   reg div

AL      Alabama 2   3

AK      Alaska  1   5

```
df = pd.DataFrame(ed,columns=['abbr','state','reg','div'])
df2=df.dropna()

print(df2)

dbCur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS loc_dim")

dbCur.execute("CREATE TABLE loc_dim(abbr text PRIMARY KEY,state text,reg integer,div integer)")

query = "INSERT INTO loc_dim (abbr, state, reg, div) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
dbCur.executemany(query, df2)

connDB.commit()
```

Getting error: "dbCur.executemany(query, df2)

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting".

Comment: Can you give us a [mcve] with sample data for that `ed` and whatever else is missing to reproduce the problem?

Comment: `print(df2)`  what did that say?

Comment: it prints the data in the df2. no error here. The error message thrown : dbCur.executemany(query, df2)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting